# Eclipse is showing return symbols with "show whitespace symbols" unchecked

Tags: eclipse

As the title says I am seeing return symbols even though I have "show whitespace characters" unchecked in text editor preferences. Can't make them go away!

[image: returns]

Comment: Restart the eclipse once

Comment: I've done this. When I check show whitespace characters they still appear on top of whats already there too, i have no idea where they are coming from.

Comment: Which editor is this? It's possible that, like PyDev's Python Editor, it's added a little something of its own that has its own preference setting (assuming you *can* turn it off).

Comment: @nitind the picture if from xml editor, but they appear on every editor. This started happening after I re installed the color theme plugin because I was having some issues with it.

Comment: Literally, when you right-click on the file, with which editor from the Open With submenu is it opening? Proper name and everything.

Comment: Using a java file as an example, `Java Editor`